# Finding the difference between days

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a table as follows to store future date,

```
 email               date 

 abc@gmail.com    8/10/2014
```

and I want to do is to find the difference between the above date and the sever date.

I'm using `date("m/d/Y")` to get the current date.

If date("m/d/Y") = 07/20/2014, then I need the answer as 21.

Please help me find the difference between those days using PHP & MySQL, or suggest a better way to find the difference in days.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3923228/328977

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: [`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert date to timestamp then calculate the days:

```
(int)(strtotime('8/10/2014')-strtotime('07/20/2014'))/60/60/24
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to store your dates as timestamps, then you could subtract the current timestamp with the one you've saved in a database.

The PHP function `time()` returns the current timestamp – that is the number of seconds since the 1st of January 1970. You can then format a timestamp `$stamp` to your liking with `date('m/d/Y', $stamp)`, for example.

Aside from facilitating arithmetic operations with dates, you can display more or less information with timestamps by formatting them with `date()`, as well as show different formats (*July 13, 2014* vs. *07/13/2014*). If you save a date as a string, e.g. "8/10/2014", it will be very complicated for you to change the format, and it won't be possible to get the correct time, for example.

Finding how long ago in days a timestamp `$stamp` was to the current time is very easy:

```
$now = time();
$days = ($stamp - $now) / (24*3600);
```

Use `round()` to get a full number if desired (e.g. `7.2309` would simply become `7`).

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally do it using DateTime:

Select your date out into a variable. In this instance We'll call it `$DBDate`

```
$DBDateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/m/Y', $DBDate);
$TodayDateObj = new DateTime();
$interval = $TodayDateObj->diff($DBDateObj);
$daysDiff = $interval->days;
```

In `$daysDiff` you should now have the difference in days.